# Rotating text on a vertical Xfce panel

Tags: xubuntu, xfce-panel

I just discovered the vertical orientation for Xfce panels, but I'd like the text on the panel applets to be rotated counterclockwise, rather than clockwise. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XFCE panel rotate window switchers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/572503/xfce-panel-rotate-window-switchers)

Comment: @AriB.Friedman Not a duplicate... your question asked for horizontal text vs. vertical... I still want vertical, but rotated 180 degrees.