# XFCE panel rotate window switchers

Tags: xfce, panel

Because laptop screens have gone to ridiculously wide format these days (grumble, grumble, uphill in snow both ways), I'd like to move my XFCE panel to the side rather than the top (i.e. run it vertically).  No problem.  However, I then want it to run the window switcher icons horizontally.

I can't even locate a set of preferences for what I believe is the Window Switcher plug-in.  Some web searches turned up a thread on the Ubuntu Forum about rotating the text in the clock, which would be nice but isn't my primary concern.  Really all I care about is the window switchers.

Here's what I have:

[image: Image of my vertical panel]

Here's what I'd like:

[image: New panel]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to choose the deskbar mode in the orientation section of desktop settings, not vertical. This will also set your text horizontal for most other plugins, like clock text and icon labels.